# Firefox 14 update with google ads not loading page

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, browser, adsense

Our webpage has 3 google adsense ads on it along with a custom dojo build.  Everything has been working great until I updated to Firefox 14.  Now the page doesn't load I'm guessing due to some javascript errors?

I've been trying to trial and error this issue.  The best I have found is that when you paste adsense code into your page there is a script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
```

if you use openX:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://d1.openx.org/ag.php'></script>
```

from what I can see, if this script is defined on the page more than once the page will not load correctly.  This has been working in older versions of FireFox.  It also works fine in chrome and IE.

Does anyone have any ideas what is going on or what changed?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I think this issue has to do with a custom build of dojo and the ad script tags.  If I remove all the ads from my page dojo works correctly and my page is fine.  I can also view all the ads on the page when dojo is not loaded.  Does anyone know how I can debug this?

Comment: Do you have a link to your site?  Also, do you have [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) installed?  If so, does it give any errors?

Comment: For some reason when I try to view http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js in any browser it wants to download it, not show it.  This could be a problem.

Comment: The script tags haven't changed.  We have always used them this way.  Firebug is installed.  It is not throwing any errors.  The page just hangs and sections relating to ads are not displayed.  It causes any dojo code to not load either.

Comment: My Firebug is getting the error: `"TypeError: window.addEvent is not a function  window.addEvent('load', function() calculator.html line 84"`

Comment: Yes I know.  That has to do with joomla.  That error has always been there.  It is not related to this issue

Comment: It appears to be a bug in FireFox.  Just tested with Aurora (Edge version of FireFox) and it works fine meaning it should be fixed in the next release of FireFox.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Any idea when the next version comes out?

Comment: You're welcome.  It looks like it is planned for August 28th. [Release dates here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Releases#Upcoming_Releases)

Comment: Thanks again.  If  you want to answer the question I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of FireFox 14 something has changed as to what gets cached.  If you edit the preferences (about:config in the url bar)  and change the parameter `network.http.use-cache` to false the website will work correctly.

I verified that this parameter is in firefox 13 and also set to true by default.  Our site works in ff 13 so something changed with the way firefox caches resources.

**EDIT**

I also realized that trying to load my 3 google adsense ads at the same time as dojo was causing issues.

I used `dojo/domReady!` before loading any dojo modules and this fixed any issues I was having.  It will also work without changing the firefox network.http.use-cache parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a bug in FireFox 14.  I can't find a bug report on http://bugzilla.mozilla.org, but I tested it with Aurora, and edge version of FireFox, which means it should be fixed in one of the next two versions of FireFox.

Aurora goes to Beta August 27th
 with FireFox 15th being released the next day.  If you want to ensure it will work with FireFox 15 try downloading the release and running it under that.

[Release date schedule here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Releases#Upcoming_Releases)

Comment: Thanks again for all your help.  I grabbed both beta and aurora but not having much luck.  When i hit the calculate button the page just sits there.  After 10 seconds it is supposed to display results.  Were you able to get it to work for you?

Comment: After 10 seconds it would display results.  You can verify on chrome or ie.  I am not sure if this has to do with the ff udate  enypting google searches.    The only work around I have found so far is to make sure those script tags are not duplicated.